# Need some editing on my responsive Slider

Tags: jquery, css

i have a [unslider](http://unslider.com/) jquery plugin , its good for me i need the links above every image , the problem is its not working when i make hover on any part of the slider , i don`t know why .. here my live example [HERE.....](http://mohammadsamy.com/slider/Index.htm)
all i need its run normal also when i hover on it . thanks all

the jquery :

```
<script>
            if(window.chrome) {
                $('.banner li').css('background-size', '100% 100%');
            }

            $('.banner').unslider({
                fluid: true,
                dots: true,
                speed: 500
            });

            //  Find any element starting with a # in the URL
            //  And listen to any click events it fires
            $('a[href^="#"]').click(function() {
                //  Find the target element
                var target = $($(this).attr('href'));

                //  And get its position
                var pos = target.offset(); // fallback to scrolling to top || {left: 0, top: 0};

                //  jQuery will return false if there's no element
                //  and your code will throw errors if it tries to do .offset().left;
                if(pos) {
                    //  Scroll the page
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: pos.top,
                        scrollLeft: pos.left
                    }, 1000);
                }

                //  Don't let them visit the url, we'll scroll you there
                return false;
            });

            var GoSquared = {acct: 'GSN-396664-U'};
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tries finally I find solution. This problem come from `js/unslider.min.js` file. That file contains the following line `this.el.hover(this.stop, this.start);` Open this file with a text/code editor (I use Notepad++) and remove the above line. Make sure you save the file. That should work.